# How to generate Non-smooth/crude Contour Lines in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, contour, smoothing

I have an SRTM DEM and I want contour lines generated for specific elevations. This can easily be done using r.contour.level/step etc. but the contours generated are smooth and cover the cells only partially (red lines in image).

Are there any methods by which I could generate a contour line that encloses the cell boundaries above a desired elevation.

Image description: Red line is the 3950m contour generated by QGIS. The yellow line is one I need: a contour enclosing all cells >= 3950m).

[image: .]

EDIT: The goal is to extract the surface area of elevation ranges (50-100,100-150 etc.) in my raster. I have a surface area raster, and the next step is to calculate zonal statistics of the raster based on a defined polygon area of interest as my contours are occur every 50m, they seemed ideal for the mask.
BUT
Using a smooth contour vector gives me incomplete zonal statistics for every elevation polygon. This is could be because the 3950 contour polygon does not "completely" enclose pixels >= 3950. In the example below, the the zonal stats only gave me data for 5 pixels. The correct data should include 12 pixels (which I manually checked to be >= 3950m) as enclosed by the yellow line.

Comment: Maybe create a temp raster as a copy of your DEM and then delete from the temp raster all those cells where ele<3950 (script this with python if you have more ranges that need to be processed) and then see if that helps you any further.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hmmm, interesting problem! Although I'm not quite sure why you'd need to do it.

I would approach it by first converting the raster to vector, either in GRASS or QGIS (it sounds like you're using both). Following that I would round the z values in the vector to your desired contour levels and then merge these together.

If you've a lot of files to process, it should be possible to automate your workflow with python.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a job for the QGIS raster calculator, have a look at "Using a Mask", here:

http://spatialgalaxy.net/2012/01/25/using-the-qgis-raster-calculator/

In your case you will only need something like (my_raster@1 >= 3950), don't use the second part of the expression shown.

You could then polygonise the output raster.

N.

Comment: @N: thanks for the link! This would be the right answer if I did not have to calculate zonal stats and only extract an elevational range throughout the raster. Since I have peak areas which are isolated at different elevations from the surrounding landscape, I will have to create vector polygons for individual peak areas. This I have already completed.